# Click on a new div

Tags: javascript

I made this little code today:

http://codepen.io/Poptocrack/pen/bgpEbr

```
document.getElementById("pays" + nb_items).onclick = function () {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'tata';
  div.setAttribute("id", "pays" + ++nb_items);
  document.getElementById("country").appendChild(div);
};
```

And i got a JS problem i think.

When i click on a div#1 it creates a new one div#2 and i would like to click on the div#2 to create a div#3 and so on.

Actually the new divs are added only if i click on the div#1.
Any idea of what did i do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The event handler doesn't automatically attach to newly added elements.

Comment: You never added `eventListener` for newly created `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind event to the parent element country instead of appending to each and every div

check this snippet

```js
var nb_items = 1;

window.onload = function() {
  var colors = ["black", "orange", "yellow"]
  document.querySelector('.country').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === "DIV") {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'tata';
      div.setAttribute("id", "pays" + ++nb_items);
      div.style.backgroundColor = colors[nb_items];
      document.getElementById("country").appendChild(div);
    }
  })

};
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-bar {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 16vh;
}
.country {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 14vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.toto {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
}
.tata {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-bar">
    <!-- Local clock -->
  </div>
  <div id="country" class="country">
    <div id="pays1" class="toto">
    </div>
    <!-- pays -->
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `eventListener` for newly created `div`

create separate `listener` function and bind it to every div created dynamically;

```
var listener = function () {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'tata';
  div.setAttribute("id", "pays" + ++nb_items);
  div.onclick = listener;
  document.getElementById("country").appendChild(div);
};
```

updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdNxXz)

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding and `eventListener` to the new created div

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'tata';
div.setAttribute("id", "pays" + ++nb_items);
div.addEventListener("click",function(){
 //create the div#3 here
 });
document.getElementById("country").appendChild(div);
```